# Adding light to an x3d scene loaded in HTML in x3dom or x_ite?

Tags: javascript, html, x3d, x3dom

Say I have the file `test.x3d` (included below), exported from Blender. Then, I can load it in an HTML page by using either [x3dom](https://www.x3dom.org/) or [X_ITE X3D Browser](http://create3000.de/x_ite/getting-started/) JS libraries. Examples for each, `load_test_x3dom.html` and `load_test_x_ite.html`, are also included below. The rendering I get is like this:

[image: ff_x3d_both.png]

I find this too dark, so I would like to increase the ambient light (or add ambient light, or any kind of light to the scene) to the scene - however, I would NOT like to modify `test.x3d` in any way.

Since I'm loading the model externally, all I have is `<inline url="test.x3d">` or `<X3DCanvas src="test.x3d">`, so it's not quite clear to me where could I add statements to additionally control the light of the scene.

So my question is: is it possible to control the lighting for a loaded `.x3d` model in x3dom/x_ite without changing the `.x3d` model itself; and if so - how?

**`load_test_x3dom.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>X3DOM load test</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://www.x3dom.org/download/1.5/x3dom.css'>
  <style>
  html, body { height: 100%; }
  x3d { width: 90%; height: 90%; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

  <p>X3DOM load test</p>

    <x3d>
      <scene>
        <inline url="test.x3d"> </inline>
      </scene>
    </x3d>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.x3dom.org/download/1.5/x3dom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**`load_test_x_ite.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>X_ITE load test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html, body { height: 100%; }
  X3DCanvas { width: 90%; height: 90%; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="content">
    <p>X_ITE load test</p>
  </div>

  <!-- X3DCanvas must not be enclosed in a div to load properly! -->
  <X3DCanvas src="test.x3d">
    <p>Your browser may not support all features required by X_ITE!</p>
  </X3DCanvas>


</body>
</html>
```

**`test.x3d`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.0//EN" "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.dtd">
<X3D version="3.0" profile="Immersive" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="filename" content="test.x3d" />
        <meta name="generator" content="Blender 2.79 (sub 0)" />
    </head>
    <Scene>
        <NavigationInfo headlight="false"
                        visibilityLimit="0.0"
                        type='"EXAMINE", "ANY"'
                        avatarSize="0.25, 1.75, 0.75"
                        />
        <Background DEF="WO_World"
                    groundColor="0.051 0.051 0.051"
                    skyColor="0.051 0.051 0.051"
                    />
        <Transform DEF="Icosphere_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                   scale="1.000000 1.000000 1.000000"
                   rotation="0.000000 0.707107 0.707107 3.141593"
                   >
            <Transform DEF="Icosphere_ifs_TRANSFORM"
                       translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                       scale="1.000000 1.000000 1.000000"
                       rotation="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                       >
                <Group DEF="group_ME_Icosphere">
                    <Shape>
                        <Appearance>
                            <Material DEF="MA_Material_001"
                                      diffuseColor="0.085 0.036 0.800"
                                      specularColor="0.401 0.115 0.104"
                                      emissiveColor="0.000 0.000 0.000"
                                      ambientIntensity="0.333"
                                      shininess="0.098"
                                      transparency="0.0"
                                      />
                        </Appearance>
                        <IndexedFaceSet solid="true"
                                        coordIndex="2 3 0 -1 0 3 7 -1 0 7 4 -1 7 6 1 -1 8 7 1 -1 6 8 1 -1 4 7 8 -1 3 6 7 -1 5 8 6 -1 5 4 8 -1 3 5 6 -1 2 5 3 -1 4 2 0 -1 2 4 5 -1 "
                                        >
                            <Coordinate DEF="coords_ME_Icosphere"
                                        point="0.209504 0.802371 -0.717194 -0.178166 0.129444 1.060728 0.178166 -0.129444 -1.060728 -1.005028 0.000000 -0.502516 1.035628 -0.125637 -0.271637 0.200539 -1.023765 -0.271638 -0.505344 -0.760048 0.740536 -0.134035 1.087594 0.305579 0.850254 0.000000 0.671351 "
                                        />
                        </IndexedFaceSet>
                    </Shape>
                </Group>
            </Transform>
        </Transform>
        <Transform DEF="Lamp_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="-4.076245 5.903862 1.005454"
                   scale="1.000000 1.000000 1.000000"
                   rotation="-0.498084 -0.762016 -0.413815 1.513875"
                   >
            <PointLight DEF="LA_Lamp"
                        ambientIntensity="0.0000"
                        color="1.0000 1.0000 1.0000"
                        intensity="0.5714"
                        radius="30.0000" 
                        location="-0.0000 -0.0000 0.0000"
                        />
        </Transform>
        <Transform DEF="Camera_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="-7.481132 5.343665 -6.507640"
                   scale="1.000000 1.000000 1.000000"
                   rotation="-0.098233 -0.968789 -0.227591 2.349487"
                   >
            <Viewpoint DEF="CA_Camera"
                       centerOfRotation="0 0 0"
                       position="-0.00 -0.00 0.00"
                       orientation="-0.00 -0.47 -0.88 0.00"
                       fieldOfView="0.858"
                       />
        </Transform>
    </Scene>
</X3D>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right - I managed to do this with X_ITE, which was a pain, since it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so for the most part I had to tediously inspect variables in Browser Console...

[image: x_ite_fix.png]

Anyways; first, in X_ITE, it is possible to do [Accessing the External Browser](http://create3000.de/x_ite/accessing-the-external-browser/) in JavaScript; then, [X_ITE X3D Browser » XHTML DOM Integration](http://create3000.de/x_ite/xhtml-dom-integration/) is achieved with an additional JS library, [x_ite_dom](https://github.com/andreasplesch/x_ite_dom).

Also, it turns out that when I try adding lights to a Scene in HTML, and I also try to Inline the `.x3d` file, something goes wrong and nothing is rendered. So, I have to load via `<X3DCanvas src="test.x3d">` as in the OP, and then iterate through its root nodes. It seems that Blender exports some five root nodes: "NavigationInfo { }", "Background { }", and 3x "Transform { }"; and to light everything up, one can use `.headlight` of the NavigationInfo root node; and also the background color can be manipulated via `.groundColor` and `.skyColor` of Background root node.

The only problem left is, that after load, the Examine mode does not quite work (i.e. the view doesn't rotate around the object); one has to double-click the object first, and then the browsing with rotation around works. Unfortunately, I cannot find how to "double-click" the object automatically on page load. Which is why I've left most of my misses as comments inside the code.

Here is the changed **`load_test_x_ite.html`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>X_ITE load test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.css"/>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js"></script>
  <!-- see: http://create3000.de/x_ite/xhtml-dom-integration/: -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/andreasplesch/x_ite_dom/master/latest/x_ite_dom.js"></script>
  <style>
  html, body { height: 100%; }
  X3DCanvas { width: 90%; height: 90%; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="content">
    <p>X_ITE load test</p>
  </div>

  <!-- X3DCanvas must not be enclosed in a div to load properly! -->
  <X3DCanvas id="browser" src="test.x3d">
    <p>Your browser may not support all features required by X_ITE!</p>
  </X3DCanvas>

    <!-- <X3DCanvas>
        <Scene>
    <!-- <Background DEF="WO_World" <!-- NOTE: this prevents the inline model from showing! -- >
                            groundColor="0.8 0.8 0.8"
                            skyColor="0.1 0.1 0.8"
            /> -- >
            <!--Viewpoint></Viewpoint-- >
            <!--NavigationInfo type='"FLY", "ANY"'></NavigationInfo-- >
      <!-- <NavigationInfo headlight='true' /> <!-- NOTE: this prevents the inline model from showing! -- >
      <!-- <PointLight color='0.99, 0.99, 0.99' /> <!-- NOTE: this prevents the inline model from showing! -- >
      <Inline DEF='myStuff' url='"test.x3d"' />
            <Transform translation='0 0 0'>
                <Inline USE='myStuff' />
            </Transform>
            <Transform translation='0 0 30'>
        <PointLight color='0.99, 0.1, 0.1' /> <!-- NOTE: this allows showing of the inline model, but no light effect is visible ! -- >
            </Transform>
        </Scene>
        <p class="fallback">
            Your browser may not support all features required by Cobweb! You can use Firefox, <br/>
            because this is currently the choice of the choice. We will continuously keep you informed <br/>
            on technical developments and as soon as Cobweb is running in other browser too.
        </p>
    </X3DCanvas> -->

<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  console.log("Window load"); // fires way before .x3d is fully loaded; first
//~   alert("Window load");
});

function printnodes(node) {
  console.log(node);
  if (typeof node.childNodes !== "undefined"){
    var childNodes = node.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      printnodes(childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}

function x_ite_callback (){ // (el) { el here is undefined
  console.log("x_ite_callback"); // this one fires after the .x3d is loaded in FF57, but ONLY if it is as attribute src; if it is inline, it fires way before model is loaded!
  var tbrowser = X3D.getBrowser("X3DCanvas#browser");
  console.log("Browser", tbrowser); // <unavailable> in Ctrl-Shift-J Browser Console of FF57, but visible in F12 Console of FF57 (visible in both in FF43)

  //~ var protoScene = document.querySelector('[DEF="myStuff"] Scene');
  //~ var protoScene = document.querySelector('Scene'); // undefined
  printnodes(tbrowser.element[0]); // this is not the X3D nodes

  // tbrowser.currentScene.namedNodes has all 3D nodes; transforms, shapes, groups etc - but not Viewpoint or NavigationInfo
  // tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes.length can be 5 for a Blender .x3d
  // tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes[0].getId() -> could be 425, 430, 434, 22046, 22053; probably internal
  // tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes[0].headlight = true; but rootNodes[1,2,3,4] might not have .headlight
  // there exists .toSource() which causes InternalError: allocation size overflow in FF57 (also "script slows down page); .toString() produces e.g. "NavigationInfo { }", "Background { }", "Transform { }" and it seems to work
  // so depending on type of x3d note (seen via .toString()), there are different properties available
  var numRootNodes = tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numRootNodes; i++) {
    var trnode = tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes[i];
    if (trnode.toString() === "Background { }") {
      //trnode.set_bind = false; // no effect here? but yes in console...
      console.log("is Background", trnode.groundColor, trnode.skyColor, trnode.isBound);
      trnode.groundColor = [{ r_: 0.051, g_: 0.451, b_: 0.051 }];
      trnode.skyColor = [{ r_: 0.051, g_: 0.051, b_: 0.451 }];
    }
        if (typeof trnode.headlight !== "undefined"){
      console.log("rootnode", i, "HAS headlight", trnode.isBound, trnode.toString());
      tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes[i].headlight = true;
    } else {
      console.log("rootnode", i, "no headlight", trnode.isBound, trnode.toString());
    }
  } // end for

  // tbrowser.currentScene.namedNodes // Object { WO_World: Proxy, Icosphere_TRANSFORM: Proxy, ...
  // tbrowser.currentScene.rootNodes[0].type[0] == "EXAMINE", [1] == "ANY"
  // http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.3/Part01/components/navigation.html#NavigationInfo:
  // ""EXAMINE" shall provide the ability to orbit or spin the user's eyepoint about the center of rotation in response to user actions. The center of rotation for moving the viewpoint around the object and determining the viewpoint orientation is specified in the currently bound X3DViewpointNode node"
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/Navigation/X3DViewer.js:                            this .getActiveViewpoint () .lookAtPoint (hit .intersection .point, 2 - 1.618034, straightenHorizon);
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/X3DBrowser.js:              changeViewpoint: function (name)
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/X3DBrowser.js:                              this .currentScene .changeViewpoint (name);
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/X3DBrowser.js:                                      this .bindViewpoint (viewpoints [0
  // ]);
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/X3DBrowser.js:              bindViewpoint: function (viewpoint)
  console.log("tbrowser.viewerNode:", tbrowser.viewerNode); // is null upon run - but OK later when called from console?!
  //~   console.log("Active Viewpoint:", tbrowser.viewerNode.getActiveViewpoint());
  // this is a function, too: tbrowser.getActiveLayer().defaultViewpoint.lookAtPoint - hard to use it to set;
  // ./src/x_ite/Browser/Navigation/ExamineViewer.js:                dblclick: function (event) ; this .lookAt (x, y);

  // stack trace upon double click // dblclick:
  // lookAt (X3DViewpointNode) https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:57547:1
  //     .. ends with:
  //         this .centerOfRotationOffset_ = Vector3 .subtract (point, this .getCenterOfRotation ());
  //         this .set_bind_               = true;
  // lookAtPoint (X3DViewpointNode) https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:57527:1
  //     this .lookAt (point, minDistance, factor, straighten);
  // lookAt  (X3DViewer)  https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:58004:5 :
  //     this .getActiveViewpoint () .lookAtPoint (hit .intersection .point, 2 - 1.618034, straightenHorizon);
  // dblclick  (ExamineViewer)  https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:58486:4 :
  //     this .lookAt (x, y);
  // dispatch https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:7362:16
  // add/elemData.handle https://rawgit.com/create3000/x_ite/master/dist/x_ite.js:7171:6

  vncheck = function() {
    if (tbrowser.viewerNode) {
      console.log("have tbrowser.viewerNode:", tbrowser.viewerNode);
      // SO:6157929
      var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        //options = options || {},
        opts = { // These are the default values, set up for un-modified left clicks
          type: 'click',
          canBubble: true,
          cancelable: true,
          view: Document.defaultView,
          detail: 1,
          screenX: 0, //The coordinates within the entire page
          screenY: 0,
          clientX: 596, //The coordinates within the viewport
          clientY: 56,
          //~ pageX: 596,
          //~ pageY: 56,
          ctrlKey: false,
          altKey: false,
          shiftKey: false,
          metaKey: false, //I *think* 'meta' is 'Cmd/Apple' on Mac, and 'Windows key' on Win. Not sure, though!
          button: 0, //0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right
          relatedTarget: null,
        };
        //Pass in the options
        event.initMouseEvent(
          opts.type,
          opts.canBubble,
          opts.cancelable,
          opts.view,
          opts.detail,
          opts.screenX,
          opts.screenY,
          opts.clientX,
          opts.clientY,
          opts.ctrlKey,
          opts.altKey,
          opts.shiftKey,
          opts.metaKey,
          opts.button,
          opts.relatedTarget
        );
      tbrowser.viewerNode.dblclick(event);
    } else {
      console.log("no tbrowser.viewerNode:", tbrowser.viewerNode);
      setTimeout(vncheck, 10);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(vncheck, 10);

  //const start = performance.now();
  //while(performance.now() - start < 1000); // busy wait; does nothing; viewerNode still null after it
  //console.log("tbrowser.viewerNode:", tbrowser.viewerNode);

} // end function x_ite_callback

function x_ite_errorCallback (error) {
  console.log("x_ite_errorCallback", error);
}
X3D (x_ite_callback, x_ite_errorCallback);

// X3D(function(el) {
//   console.log("el", el); // also undefined here, FF57
// });


var Browser;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("Window complete"); // fires way before .x3d is fully loaded; second
//~     alert("Window complete");
    // Obtain X3DBrowser object of X3DCanvas element with id »browser«.
    var tbrowser = X3D.getBrowser("X3DCanvas#browser"); // no var here, so we set the global? This is randomly either undefined or defined in FF 43; but in FF 57 is always undefined
    //Browser = tbrowser;
    console.log("Browser", tbrowser); //, tbrowser);
  }
}, 100);

//~ var intervalB = setInterval(function() { // this one never clears..
//~   if (typeof Browser !== "undefined") { //if (Browser.hasOwnProperty("loading")) {
//~     if (Browser.loading === false) {
//~       clearInterval(intervalB);
//~       console.log("Browser loaded");
//~       alert("Browser loaded");
//~     }
//~   }
//~ }, 100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```